# How to build app for Facebook submission

Tags: ios, facebook, xcode6, ios-simulator

I have app that need to submit on Facebook for review.
The steps to create app for Facebook are given here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/creating-ios-simulator-build-for-review

But i have simulators shown below:
[image]

the command to build app shown in Facebook link is for simulator of iOS 7.1 now what command did I use to build my app?
I am using Xcode 6.1.1 . Also for which sdks i should build my app to submit on Facebook?
Please provide command for build and run that app in simulator to test .

Comment: always try in new SDKS

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik yes , but the command to make app is for iOS 7.1 what is command for 8.1 sdks?

Comment: i also did in iOS 7.1 , but Facebook does not update the documents, just try if it works fine otherwise continue iOS 7.1

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Can you tell me command to make app for iOS 8.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your coding is fine continue the further work

```
//run this command 

 xcodebuild -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator8.1
```

you getting the following result

> This should generate a build. If the build was successful you should see a lot of output from the build tools followed by the string ** BUILD SUCCEEDED ** in your terminal.

try this to resolve the `failure`

**choice no - 1**

```
xcodebuild -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator{version} -workspace [projectName].xcworkspace -scheme [projectName]
```

need help use this [link](http://simulatorbuild.blogspot.in/p/generate-simulator-build-in-order-to.html)

**choice no - 2**

```
xcodebuild -workspace {project name}.xcworkspace -scheme {project name}  -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator8.1
```

> The FB instructions say the .app file should be in: {base directory}/build/Release-iphonesimulator/{projectname}.app
>
> it ended up in /Developer/Derived Data/{project name}-{long string of random letters}/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator

Comment: further continue the next step, if u need assistance i hope with u

Comment: Are you sure this command is working for you?I am getting below error:
 The following build commands failed:
 Ld build/Release-iphonesimulator/AppName.app/AppName normal i386
(1 failure)

Answer (score 0):

Run your app on simulator and go to location **~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*/Build/Products/*-iphonesimulator/XXXX.app** copy your **.app** file at any location create a compress **zip file** .submit this zip file to fb